# Self join on joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, self-join

My query looks like

```
Select m.cw_sport_match_id as MatchId,
       m.season_id as SeasonId,
       s.title as SeasonName,
       c.title as ContestName
from dbo.cw_sport_match m
inner join dbo.cw_sport_season s
  ON m.season_id = s.cw_sport_season_id
inner join dbo.cw_sport_contest c
  ON m.contest_id = c.cw_sport_contest_id
Where s.date_start <= GETDATE() AND s.date_end >= GETDATE()
order by s.date_start
```

No i need the name parent of the sport_contest (if there is one, it can be null). So basically a self join but no on the same table as the query is for. All the examples that i find do the self join are not done on another table.
can any sql pro help me?
So how can i join the cw_sport_season itself with the season_parent_id and get the title of it?

Comment: Why are you calling it a self join if your not joining to the same table? Can you please clarify.

Comment: `self join are not on another table`? If they're on another table, then it's not a self-join, it's just a join.

Comment: okey i am sorry, i thought a self join is if i join a reference to the same table again. in that case it is not self join i just want to join a reference on a joined table to the joined table itself... ^^

Comment: wow, this gets obscure. Can you add some data / schema and expected results. Try to explain it in human words without "self join".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to `outer join` the `cw_sport_season` table to itself using the `season_parent_id` field.  Maybe something on these lines:

```
Select m.cw_sport_match_id as MatchId,
       m.season_id as SeasonId,
       s.title as SeasonName,
       parent.title as ParentSeasonName,
       c.title as ContestName
from dbo.cw_sport_match m
inner join dbo.cw_sport_season s
  ON m.season_id = s.cw_sport_season_id
inner join dbo.cw_sport_contest c
  ON m.contest_id = c.cw_sport_contest_id
left join dbo.cw_sport_season parent
  ON s.season_parent_id = parent.cw_sport_season_id
Where s.date_start <= GETDATE() AND s.date_end >= GETDATE()
order by s.date_start
```